# Trying to change the background color in one activity from code in another activity (Kotlin/Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-activity, kotlin, radio-button

I am programming in Kotlin in Android Studio 3.1.3.  I am trying to create an activity that changes its background color to any of 16 colors from clicking on a button.  The app is for my 7 year old niece, so a simpler interface would be preferable.

My approach is to use a button to bring up a second activity that contains radio buttons to select a color.  After the color is selected, I would like to return to the first activity and automatically change the color of the Constraint Layout background.  I can achieve this by using a second button, but have not had success with using a single button (the preferred approach).

Below is the very simple code of the main activity at this point, including the functions called by the two buttons that make this work.  The functions are called using the onClick events of the buttons in xml (also shown below).

Note that the "var color ..." statement is outside the MainActivity class so that it can be accessed across all activities in the project.  It is changed in the second activity, and I would like to use that result to change the background color in the first activity.

var color_Background: Int = color_White

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
}

fun setColor_click (view: View) {
    val intent_ChangeColor = Intent (this, ChangeColor :: class.java)
    startActivity (intent_ChangeColor)
}

fun changeColor_click (view: View) {
    val cl: ConstraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.constraint_Layout)
    cl.setBackgroundColor(color_Background)
}
```

}

The two functions above are called by xml onClick events for the buttons, like this.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_SetColor"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:onClick="setColor_click"
    android:text="@string/set_color"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

The second activity contains a bunch of functions, one for each color, that modify variable "color_Background", like this  (note: I tried the following code with and without the "return" statement):

```
fun Red_clicked(view: View) {
    color_Background = color_Red
    finish()
    return
}
```

Again, each "color" function is called by an xml onClick event for its corresponding radio button, like this.

```
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rad_Red"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="Red_clicked"
        android:text="Red"
        android:buttonTint="@color/White"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
```

I have tried placing the following code in onCreate, onResume and onRestart methods in the Main activity, to no avail.  Note that this is the code executed "on click" of the second button in the MainActivity that I am trying to eliminate.

```
    val cl: ConstraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.constraint_Layout)
    cl.setBackgroundColor(color_Background)
```

I read about the Activity lifecycle, which is why I tried various "on" methods.  I also tried a bunch of combinations of programming options, but the only way I have been able to get it to work is with two buttons.

Any thoughts on how I can get the setting of the background color in the MainActivity changed to one of 16 colors using a single button would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you probably want to look into is `startActivityForResult`. You can pass an `int`, and your `Activity` can be notified when it returns the result.

```
// Define some constants, the request code and the place we're passing the result.
companion object {
    private const val COLOR_REQUEST= 10001
    const val EXTRA_COLOR = "EXTRA_COLOR"
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
}

// Now, call startActivityForResult instead, passing the request code.

fun setColor_click (view: View) {
    val intent = Intent (this, ChangeColor::class.java)
    startActivityForResult(intent, COLOR_REQUEST)
}

fun changeColor_click (view: View) {
    val cl: ConstraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.constraint_Layout)
    cl.setBackgroundColor(color_Background)
}

// And now you can handle the result.

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    if( requestCode == COLOR_RESULT && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null  ) {
        val color = data.extras.getInt(EXTRA_COLOR)
        // TODO use the color.
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
}
```

Now, in your `ChangeColor` `Activity`, you want to make sure you return the colour when calling `finish`.

```
fun Red_clicked(view: View) {
    val intent = Intent()
    intent.putExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_COLOR, color_Red)
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent)
    finish()
    return
}
```

And there you go. You'll want to change it and maybe pass something easier. But the `id` of the color should work for now.

Answer (score 0):

After further research and experimentation, I discovered the following additional solution.

Add the following onStart function in the main activity (class MainActivity).  This is apparently executed when a) the app is first started and also b) when the app transfers control from the second activity back to the first.

```
override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()  
        val cl: ConstraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.constraint_Layout)
        cl.setBackgroundColor(color_Background)
}
```